# Proving there are infinite solutions to an equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm somewhat stuck on what the correct answer to this question would be:

> Show that there are infinitely many integral solutions of
>   $$1947 \times m + 264 \times n = 33$$

So it's pretty easy to see that there are infinitely many solutions, but I'm not sure exactly how I should go about *showing* it.

Comment: Could you explain to us why it's "pretty easy to see"?

Comment: Sure, so since m and n can be any numbers, if you were to keep iterating through positive integers for m, you'd be bound to find corresponding n values for some of them that satisfy the equation. I suppose I'd then need to find the pattern for these values that satisfy the equation, meaning I'd probably need to introduce a new constant that could be used to describe these values in separate equations for m and n?

Comment: @Michael: how does your analysis work with $35m + 21n = 6$?

Comment: Since 6 doesn't divide the left side of the equation, I'd probably say (guess) that you'd have a hard time finding an *integer* solution. So the fact that 33 is the gcd is probably important

Comment: One common way is to set m = something to do with n (por vice versa) therefor for all the infinite values m could be n could be a consistant value.

Comment: Oh, *integer* solutions.  Slightly different.  Not harder.  Note if 1947xm +264x n =33 is a solution, then 1947x (m+264) + 264 (n-1947) =33$ is also a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that there is at least one solution $(m_0,n_0)$, because $33$ is the gcd of $1947$ and $264$.

And given this solution, we can construct new solutions $(m,n)=(m_0+264k,n_0-1947k)$ for any integer $k$.